# DIV Overlapping But Not Hiding The Portion Of the DIV That It Overlaps

Tags: html, css

This could be a very simple problem.  Or a well known limitation.

I have two divs.  I would like the first div *front* to overlap the second div *back*.  I am able to achieve that.

My problem is that the first div is transparent.  I am unable to get it to completely hide the portion of second div that it overlaps.

Below is the HTML.

```
    <div class="front">
        <div>My first div</div>
        <div>My first div</div>
        <div>My first div</div>
    </div>

    <div class="back">
        <div>My second div</div>
        <div>My second div</div>
        <div>My second div</div>
        <div>My second div</div>
        <div>My second div</div>
        <div>My second div</div>
    </div>
```

Below is the css.

```
    div.front {
        height:60px;
        width:100px;
        border:3px solid blue;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:1;
    }
    div.back {
        background-color:#e0e0e0; 
        border:1px solid red;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:-1;
    }
```

You can find the JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/tomilay/p372u894/3/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p372u894/4/  ???  set a background equal to the background where those dives will live.

Comment: It is because you are using a transparent background for the front div.

Comment: This is simly impossible. The opacity makes the front div transparent and all content behind it will be visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the front most div a background color.

```
    div.front {
        height:60px;
        width:100px;
        border:3px solid blue;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:1;
        background-color: white;
    }
    div.back {
        background-color:#e0e0e0; 
        border:1px solid red;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:-1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you just said, the `background-color` of `front` is transparent so you will se what is behind it. Try seting a `background-color` different than transparent for this to work as youw want:

JSFiddle sample: http://jsfiddle.net/p372u894/7/

CSS updated:

```
div.front {
    height:60px;
    width:100px;
    border:3px solid blue;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    background-color: white; /* Setting background-color */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a grey background-color to your `<div>` with the `front` class.

```
div.front {
    height:60px;
    width:100px;
    border:3px solid blue;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:#e0e0e0; 
}
```

Please check this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p372u894/6/).